# Не устанавливается Android Build Support на Unity

Tags: c#, android, linux, unity3d, unity-hub

Я хочу разрабатывать игры для мобильных. Я перерыл весь интернет, но так и не нашёл ответ. Вообщем, я использую Unity Hub, но когда я пытаюсь добавить Android модуль, он долго устанавливается... но не добавляется! Я перепробывал и много других вариантов, но они никак не помогают. Это пока всё, что я могу написать. Надеюсь вы сможете мне помочь. Если что, я сижу на линуксе. Спасибо.